# Drupal 8 jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, browserify, shim

On the front end part of my Drupal 8 project, I have several javascript modules linked together using Browserify (and gulp).

In several modules I use Foundation, and the way Foundation is made is that it adds a `foundation()` function to the `$` object.

This is an excerpt of my package.json where I declared the shims that my project needs :

```
"browser": {
    "jwplayer": "./libraries/utils/jwplayer/jwplayer.js",
    "Foundation": "./node_modules/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js",
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "Backbone": "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
    "underscore": "./node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "underscore": "_",
    "jwplayer": "jwplayer",
    "Foundation": {
      "exports": null,
      "depends": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    },
    "Backbone": {
      "exports": "Backbone",
      "depends": [
        "jquery",
        "underscore"
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
```

Everything works great when I'm logged out of the Drupal admin.

Although when I'm logged as an admin, Drupal adds a small taskbar on the top, helping you to access the different access menus, and a couple other useful stuff.

When Drupal does that, it uses its own version of jQuery, and attach a certain amount of plugins to it.

Now when I export my own `jQuery` and declare it as `$` in my *package.json* file, I obviously erase Drupal's `jQuery` and all the plugins that came with it, destroying the topbar.

How can I possibly tell Foundation and every module or plugin that needs jQuery to use the Drupal one, and not the one in my *node_modules* folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking around stackoverflow I found this [How do I use Browserify with external dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125338/how-do-i-use-browserify-with-external-dependencies)
and I replaced

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
}
```

with

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:jQuery"
}
```

It works perfectly now. It is kind of weird that I still have to do 
`var $ = require('jquery');` inside my modules though. If anyone has more informations about that I'm all ears.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I still have to require it as well like this `var $ = jQuery;`