# How do I exclude the "require('react')" from my Browserified bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm using `Browserify` to bundle a `ReactJS` application.

All my components include a `require("react")` at the top. This causes `Browserify` to include the `ReactJS` source in my bundle. But I'd like to exclude it.

How do I do that? Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

@NickTomlin gave this answer, but then deleted it.

---

You can use [`external`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#bexternalfile):

`browserify --external react src.js > dest.js`

An example using the api:

```
var bundler = browserify('src.js');

bundler.external('react');
bundler.bundle();
```

---

This is a viable option.  `external` requires another script to provide the module in a compatible way.  You can produce such a script like this:

```
browserify -r react > react.js
env NODE_ENV=production browserify -r react | uglifyjs -m > react.min.js
```

And in HTML:

```
<script src="react.js"></script>
<script src="dest.js"></script>
```

dest.js is your code except react.  react.js is just react and its dependencies.

Need more things external?  Just add them in addition to react.

```
browserify -x react -x react-bootstrap src.js > dest.js
browserify -r react -r react-bootstrap > vendor.js
```

You could also do something like this in package.json

```
"browser": {"react": "./react-fake.js"}
```

```
// ./react-fake.js
try {
    module.exports = require('react');
} catch(e){
    module.exports = window.React;
}
```

And compile with `-x react`.  This allows you to accept a `-r react` build, and fallback to a global React.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the middle code block. The output file name for the first browserify should be dest.js rather than vendor.js, otherwise the second browserify will overwrite the first.

Comment: The problem is, `browser` is just a transform, so it does not apply to your node_modules. So if you have any node_modules libraries that reference react then they will throw a "modules not found" error.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want to use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim).

In your `package.json`

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "react": "global:React"
},
"browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
},
"dependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "~3.2.0"
}
```

(untested). [This section](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global) has more information.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125338/how-do-i-use-browserify-with-external-dependencies

Comment: I am having lots of trouble with browserify-shim.
I have a umd module that i'm trying to browserify, and its not changing the modules require('foo') calls to global['Foo'] even though my package.json specifies browserify-shim: { 'foo': 'global:Foo' }. Do i need to target that module somehow? like browserify-shim: { 'mod': { depends: "foo" }}

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to do this, and found a possible solution.

From the `browserify -h` help:

> --ignore, -i  Replace a file with an empty stub. Files can be globs.

Just use the **ignore** feature.

```
browserify -i react -i react-dom ...
```

I also added react and react-dom as peer dependencies, cause in my case, the package can be imported in other packages builds.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the externals section in the webpack.config.js file.  eg:-

```
externals: {
        // require('jquery') is loaded externally and avaliable as jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
```

See https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html