# Size of bundled ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, npm, bundle, browserify, reactify

I am trying to reduce the size of my reactjs application bundle.js file. For a relatively simple app i have its browserified js file size - 452Kb.

To build it, i use NPM with respective package.json file:

```
   {
      "name": "MyApp-React",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "description": "My App Description",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "watch": "watchify app.js -o public/js/bundle.js -v",
        "browserify": "browserify app.js | uglifyjs > public/js/bundle.js",
        "build": "npm run browserify",
        "start": "npm install"
      },
      "author": "",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.14.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
        "clipboard": "^1.5.12",
        "express": "~4.9.7",
        "express-handlebars": "~1.1.0",
        "express-session": "^1.14.1",
        "highlight.js": "^9.7.0",
        "node-jsx": "~0.12.4",
        "react": "~15.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
        "react-maskedinput": "^3.2.4",
        "react-modal": "^1.4.0",
        "react-router": "^2.8.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "browserify": "~6.0.3",
        "nodemon": "^1.2.1",
        "reactify": "~1.1.1",
        "uglify-js": "~2.4.15",
        "watchify": "^3.1.1"
      },
      "browserify": {
        "debug": false,
        "transform": [
          "reactify"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Not being an expert in Node JS/ ReactJS development i hope i do somethin wrong, but i cant find what.

For the time being i tried few things: app.js file has a line of code setting NODE_ENV variable to 'production'

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
```

A second thing i have tried is to use npm prune command with --production parameter. Having this run, i see it removes a lot from node_modules folder, but then npm run build is failing to run as it misses devDependencies. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you could do to lighten the download burden for your users is get *react* and *react-dom* from a CDN instead of putting them in your bundle.

Move them from the *dependencies* section of your *package.json* to a new section *peerDependencies* ([see npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies)).

Then add  tags to your HTML code for loading React and ReactDOM like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

→ See [React on cdnjs.com](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/)

Then you need to change your Browserify config to recognize *react* and *react-dom* as external modules.

→ See [related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222745/how-do-i-exclude-the-requirereact-from-my-browserified-bundle)

Comment: Removing express  (and for-express modules) does not help. Size does not change at all. Having moved react and react-dom into html file, i get  Cannot find module 'react' from '...', when runnning build command

Comment: I'm not familiar with Browserify, I suspect you'll have to configure it to recognize that react and react-dom are coming from a CDN. In Webpack, which I'm using, you configure aliases for them.

Comment: Removed the part about express from my answer