# Browserify with already browserified files

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

Using browserify, I'm attempting to require an already browserified module, but the bundle is not able to resolve the module that has already been browserified.

For example, I have a file `bundle-1.js` that has been bundled with the command:

```
browserify -r ./bundle-1:bundle.one > build/bundle.one.js
```

I have another file, `bundle-2.js` that has `require('bundle.two')`, which is bundled with the command:

```
browserify -r ./bundle-2:bundle.two -x ./build/bundle.one.js > build/bundle.two.js
```

Attempting to run that last command, produces an error stating `Cannot find module 'bundle.one'`.

How can I expose the modules from `bundle-1` for `bundle-2` to use from the module name `bundle.one`?

I've created a repo for this example here: https://github.com/kand/browserify-bundling-tests

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because browserified bundle is already wrapped by browserify and does not look like node.js module (commonjs, containing `require()` and `exports`) statements. It should be possible to specify previous bundle as a global library exporting some object in browserify configuration.

Solution is similar to importing any other global library as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125338/how-do-i-use-browserify-with-external-dependencies).