# importing Typescript @types causes browserify to error

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm getting an error when I run browserify in gulp with a import statement. I can get it to bundle without it but then I get type errors. I have several files importing a type, however, when I try to run browserify I get

Error: Cannot find module 'chart.js' from '/Users/lonniemcgill/Desktop/Projects/Typescript/ssadmin/development/assets/ts/views'

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "files": [
        "ts/main.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
        "types": ["jquery", "chart.js"],
        "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

and my import looks like this:

```
import * as Chart from "chart.js";
```

visual studio code recognizes it is a type because intellisence isn't giving me any errors. Without the import it will work but I get a bunch of type errors. How can I get browserify to bundle with the import statement included?

Here is my gulp code for that task.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify({
           basedir: '.',
           debug: true,
           entries: ['ts/main.ts'],
           cache: {},
           packageCache: {}
        })
       .plugin(tsify)
       .transform(babelify, {
           presets: ['es2015'],
           extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
       })
       .bundle()
       .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
       .pipe(buffer())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest("js/compiled"));
});
```

Comment: Are you loading chart.js via a script tag? Load it as a module (preferred), or create a `declare global` type shim. There may also be some Browserify specific way to map it.

Comment: I've compiled all my bower components into a vendor.js file and have it loaded in a script tag.

Comment: Then that is why

Comment: Including the Chart.js file separately doesn't fix the issue. Chart.js is working. This has to do with the compiler not recognizing the  path to node_modules/@types/bundle.js and looking for the module in my view file. I need browserify to recognize the @types. I am trying to import the file to resolve the typescript type error.

Comment: No that is not what is happening. What is happening is that, since you use the import in value position, it is not elided. Since it is not elided Browserify tries to import it from node_modules/chart.js. I recommend that you install it with npm

Comment: I have it already the package installed with npm and it is in my package.json. It is looking for the module in the wrong folder when compiling with browserify which causes the error. If I take out the import statement the project still functions but I get the type error. So including the chart.js directly in a script doesn't resolve the type error.

Comment: That is because Browserify does not know about that bundle that is loaded via a separate script tag when it builds the bundle containing the import.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the import in value position (as opposed to solely in type position), typescript does not elide it. This means the emitted JavaScript has the `import` (transpiled as a `require`).

Browserify will thusly try to import it from `node_modules`.

To fix the error, you have a few options:

1. install chart.js with npm

   ```
   npm install --save chart.js
   ```

   then remove it from your vendor bundle.

   This should be the preferred approach. This is one of the main reasons to use tools like Browserify or Webpack.
2. Create a global declaration for chart.js so that you do not have to import it.

   ```
   import chartjs = require('chart.js');
   declare global {
     const Chart = chartjs;
   }
   ```

   Then remove the import.
3. Use a Browserify specific configuration technique to tell it that chart.js actually maps to a global.

   This answer explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23129051/1915893

Answer (score -2):

For those of you who are interested I found the answer in the typescript documents. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html `Use /// <reference types="chart.js" />` or whatever your @type is. instead of import so that it is compatible with typescript.